# Adding to vue.js value just adds number to the end

Tags: vue.js

Strange issue, I am trying to create a pagination system and I am trying to increase the next page value by 1. However as you can see the value is appended instead of increasing the value.

> this.page = 1

```
<a v-if="this.total_pages > this.page" class="link" :href="'/cryptocurrency/market-cap?p='+(this.page + 1)">></a>
```

The above returns `p=11` vue seems to append the 1 to the original page value of 1 instead of increasing the page value to 2.

If however I do the following it seems to work and decreases the p value by 1.

```
<a v-if="this.total_pages > 1 & this.page > 1" class="link" :href="'/cryptocurrency/market-cap?p='+(this.page - 1)" ><</a>
```

Comment: Is `this.page` a string or a number? If it is a string, you will need to convert it to a number first, i.e. `(+this.page + 1)`

Comment: And it should be `&&`, not `&`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a Vue issue. It's more likely you're running into JS' loose type casting. I assume `this.page` is not a `number` but a `string` value. Therefore you're adding `'1' + 1` in the first example which leads to 11 (since JS treats both as string and concatenates them).

However, if you're trying tu do something like `'1' - 1` JS casts the initial 1 as a number instead and resolve the calculation properly.

So to solve your problem you just have to use a proper type for `this.page` or cast it to a number on execution, like this:

`<a :href="'/cryptocurrency/market-cap?p='+(parseInt(this.page)+ 1)">></a>`

Comment: Thanks yes this was the problem, I ended up adding the following and it has done the trick this.page = parseInt(urlParams.get('p'));